# How to delete list objects in Django?

Tags: django, django-views

I was always been taught, if you create array or list, you have to delete this array or list object. So if you append (push) , then you have to pop and delete. Otherwise this object will create bad references on the hard drive and eventually eat up the disk space with the bad fragments.

In Django, I cannot find any info on how properly dispose temporary objects. Especially, after using them in template (so, like, redirecting them from view function into the template). Even more... I can pop from list of object like this:

```
if  a_object:
            while a_object:
                a_object.pop()
            print('deleted a_object')
```

But as soon as I try something like:

```
delete a_object
```

Django tells me that there is no such function...

And also, how would I pop items from list if I redirect from view function to template, so I am gone from view function and cannot pop items from list object neither before going to template, nor after I'm gone to template.

Any thoughts on this? Because I am confused... Does Django automatically take care of objects as a higher level language?

Comment: How are the elements in your object created? Why do you say they are stored on the hard drive?

Comment: I am doing my project on a local machine... To say they are stored on a hard drive, probably is a poor expression. I think it's better to say they temporary occupy local resources, while objects are created. Thank you for the answer. I was guessing it was higher level language, which takes care of such things, but I just wanted to ask the question.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Python is a [garbage collected](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Garbage_collection_(computer_science)) language, so it takes care of freeing memory occupied by objects that are no longer in use by the program

You can make that explicit by using the [del](https://docs.python.org/3/reference/simple_stmts.html#del) statement, which  "removes the binding of that name from the local or global namespace" (so using `del a_object`), but that's not necessary.

As long as a variable is not "reachable" from your code anymore, it will get deleted automatically